# Python How to start Thread inside another one?

Tags: multithreading, events

I'm trying to start multiple thread, and the start time of the next thread will depend on what It'll happend in the first and etc.

So I found some post in Stackoverflow like this one in the answer he talk about the Event class:
[Python threading - How to repeatedly execute a function in a separate thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049861/python-threading-how-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-in-a-separate-thread)

So I try to do in that way :

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import time

class MyThread3(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = event

    def run(self):
        while self.stopped.wait(0.5):
            print("The Third thread is running..")


class MyThread2(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = event

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        my_event2.clear()
        time.sleep(3)
        my_event.set()
        time.sleep(2)
        my_event2.set()

class MyThread1(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = event

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped.wait(0.5):
            print("Thread is running..")

my_event = Event()
my_event2 = Event()
thread1 = MyThread1(my_event)
thread2 = MyThread2(my_event)
thread3 = MyThread3(my_event2)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
thread3.join()
```

If I put while not in the Thread3 it start at the same time as the Thread1, so why if I put the opposit and if the state of the Event change and it doesn't start ?
We cannot change an Event inside a Thread ?
How can I start a thread from another Thread ?

Comment: What do you mean by "starting the thread"? Usual meaning is that `.start` method starts the thread. Note also, that you use private `my_event2` for the thread3, (both other threads use `my_event`). So you are hardly can control thread3 execution from other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Hum that's true you're right I even dindn't think about that.

there is the solution that I found :

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Event

class MyThread1(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = event

    def run(self):
        x = 0
        while not self.stopped.wait(0.5):
            if x == 5:
                    thread2.start()
            print("Thread 1 is running..")
            x += 1


class MyThread2(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("Procces 2 start and the process 1 will stop in 2 seconds")
        x = 0
        while x < 10:
            if x == 5:
                my_event.set()
            print("x = ",x)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            x += 1

my_event = Event()
thread1 = MyThread1(my_event)
thread2 = MyThread2()

thread1.start()
```

The solution that I found seems not very nice, any other suggestion to have a clean code ?

And I have also another question about this kind of multithreading, how can we use a variable in a thread to use it in another thread ?

For exemple :

Thread 1 is running
Thread 2 is running

thread 1 is waiting 10min and will check a variable Default
thread 2 calculate something and change the variable Default to 20

after the 10min waiting of the thread 1, see that the value of Default is 20 and do a task, if not he will end.